# How to take a photo in landscape mode [iOS8]?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

I've got an application where I need to take a photo and then make png layer by drawing on it. My png layer is absolutely correct and has a landscape dimension.

But when I upload my taken photo, it has the portrait dimension.

```
 - (void)takePhoto {
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in StillImageOutput.connections) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    [StillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
        if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            UIImage *ipadImage = [self imageRotatedByDegrees:image deg:0];

            NSLog(@"image orientation: %ld", (long)image.imageOrientation);
            NSLog(@"image width: %f , height: %f", image.size.width, image.size.height);

            captured.image = ipadImage;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple uses the EXIF tag to specify orientation and always uses the same dimension orientation (landscape) regardless of how the phone was held when the photo was taken. Most platforms do not take the EXIF orientation in to account and that presents an interoperability problem.

For interoperabiity it may be necessary to rotate the image prior to uploading and change the EXIF tag to match.

See [EXIF Orientation Handling Is a Ghetto](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/) for more information.